# QGIS raster symbology problem in 2.6

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, color, qgis-2.6

With the new 2.6 QGIS version I often have problems with raster colors. For some reason certain pixels do not display initially, but if I move the raster a little spatially they show up.

[image]

Comment: try to load the actual min/max values and then apply your color palette. Go to the layer proprties, style tab, and then in the load min/max values choose min/max and in the accuracy section choose actual and chose the load button. Then apply the color pálette of your choice.

Comment: Could you describe more about what you mean by problems? Are you talking about the colors chosen, or the fact that there are gaps/nodata cells? You also mention a legend but don't show an example. For the image you posted, this is usually a color ramp or specific patches at certain intervals on such a ramp.

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that there are cells without any color. But when I move the raster map a little bit to the right side the colors will be shown. I do have this problem with different kind of maps but only with the new version 2.6.

Comment: I've made an edit to hopefully make the question easier to understand and attract attention from knowledgeable people (please correct anything I might have misstated). You might edit the question to also include a screenshot of your symbology settings dialog.

Comment: Ok. I did change the picture. Now you can see the legend and the value (showen by the value tool).